# Spring - periodic reload properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there any way to reload properties from `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and refresh `@Value` renderer ?

```
@Bean
public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() throws Exception {
    final ClassPathResource classPathRessource = new ClassPathResource(PROPERTIES_FILE);
    final Properties fileProperties = loadDbPropertiesFromInputStream(classPathRessource.getInputStream());

    // Instantiate properties dataSource
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(fileProperties.getProperty(PROPERTY_KEY_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(fileProperties.getProperty(PROPERTY_KEY_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(fileProperties.getProperty(PROPERTY_KEY_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(fileProperties.getProperty(PROPERTY_KEY_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    // Init PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
    final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(classPathRessource);

    // Add properties from defined database
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setPropertiesArray(ConfigurationConverter.getProperties(getDatabaseConfiguration(dataSource)));

    return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

Properties are loaded from Database and if database change, I should restart backend server.. So have any to avoid this ?

Thank you

Comment: You should take a look at spring-cloud. idk if it allows from db, but it is possible from versioned files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices :

- Through **Spring Boot Actuator**
- Through **Spring Cloud Bus**

## Option 1 : Through Spring Boot Actuator.

Add the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency in **pom.xml** :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When add new changes and you want see that, then you have to call this url :

```
http://ip:port/actuator/refresh
```

But the problem is that the refresh happens at individual server.

## Option 2 : Through Spring Cloud Bus

But for this you have to use some messaging queue system like Kafka, RabbitMQ and so on.

I will show with RabbitMQ only.

- First install Rabbit MQ and run it
- Add configuration in application.properties to connect to Rabbit MQ.

Read here : https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-spring-amqp.html

Add the `spring-boot-starter-amqp` & `spring-boot-starter-actuator` in the *pom.xml* :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When add new changes and you want see that, then you have to call this url :

```
http://ip:port/actuator/bus-refresh
```

Plus Point : The refresh happens on all the servers.

Note: You can use `@RefreshScope` to auto refresh the `@Value` renderers. Example :

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class AppConfig {
   
   @Value("${some.value}")
   private String value;
   
   @Bean
   public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() throws Exception {
    final ClassPathResource classPathRessource = new ClassPathResource(PROPERTIES_FILE);
    final Properties fileProperties = loadDbPropertiesFromInputStream(classPathRessource.getInputStream());

    // Instantiate properties dataSource
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(fileProperties.getProperty(PROPERTY_KEY_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(fileProperties.getProperty(PROPERTY_KEY_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(fileProperties.getProperty(PROPERTY_KEY_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(fileProperties.getProperty(PROPERTY_KEY_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    // Init PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
    final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(classPathRessource);

    // Add properties from defined database
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setPropertiesArray(ConfigurationConverter.getProperties(getDatabaseConfiguration(dataSource)));

    return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring provides Spring cloud bus for such case, you can use it to refresh data without restarting the server, moreover you can use it to refresh multiple instances for your application.